# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rec'

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to to call a class's constructor but it is giving me the below error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rec'

And I have the same issue with listen() as below. Please discard the `rms()`and`record()`since they are other functions And here is my code:

```
class Recorder:

    def __init__(rec):
        rec.p= pyaudio.PyAudio()
        rec.stream= rec.p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE,input=True,output=True,frames_per_buffer=chunk)


    # listen to the sound
    def listen(rec):
        print('Listening beginning')
        while True:
            input = rec.stream.read(chunk, execption_on_overflow=False)
            rms_val = rec.rms(input)
            if rms_val > Threshold:
                rec.record()

k = Recorder()
k.listen()
```

Comment: Try renaming "rec" to "self". I'm not sure, but that might solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure that’s what the code running actually looks like? (Well, the indentation is wrong, but I’m referring to `__init__(rec)`. The error would make more sense with `__init__(self, rec)`.)

Comment: @Rafael That won't. Using the name `self` is just a convention, you could use anything else instead.

Comment: Also, please show the stack trace. (Is the error coming from your constructor, or from `pyaudio.PyAudio`?)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ah ok thanks, I was not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

mmh I can not reproduce the error. I only focus on the `__init__` method, because that is your crucial part.

**Test.py**

```
import pyaudio

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

class Recorder:
    def __init__(rec):
        rec.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        rec.stream = rec.p.open(format = FORMAT, channels = CHANNELS, rate = RATE, input = True, output = True, frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

    # listen to the sound
    def listen(rec):
        print('Listening beginning')

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    k = Recorder()
    k.listen()

>> python Test.py
>> Listening beginning
```

And my setup

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pyaudio
>>> print(pyaudio.__version__)
0.2.11
```

So please specify your versions and give some additional informations about your problem.

I assume that you use a constructor like

```
def __init__(self, rec):
   ...
```

but you don´t pass any argument to `rec`. This would explain your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Test.py", line 20, in <module>
    k = Recorder()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rec'
```

Comment: Hi, it's the same version of 0.2.11. And I use  def __init__(rec) without self.

Comment: Then there should be no error (see my example above).

Comment: @ Kampi The error is still existed with saying: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rec'. And I am trying to upload mu full code.

Comment: Please review your given code. I copy your code and define the unknown variables. With your complete code I got the error `TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'execption_on_overflow'` which is different from your error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497460/error-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-rec

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in others methods and your code not show all... Record has others methods like "record" and "rms".

def listen(rec):

print('Listening beginning')

while True:

input = rec.stream.read(chunk, execption_on_overflow=False)

rms_val = **rec.rms(input)** # How I now if your errors it occuring here?

if rms_val > Threshold:

**rec.record()** # Or them here?

I can't now if your are calling the **init**() function in this methods...

Comment: The problem occur in the `__init__` method (see error message) and this method doesn´t use a method named `rms`. 
Additional you get other error messages with this error. The error message say something like a parameter error and not a unknown method error.

Comment: I can't now if your are calling the __init__() function in this methods...

Comment: @Daniel A R F. My full code is here:　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497460/error-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-rec＼